# Event handler has dependency on call order

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, refactoring, anti-patterns

On `WinForm` there is `TreeView` control.

In `AfterSelect` event is private field `selectedFolder` updated.

For event `OnKeyDown` for `Delete` key is event handler implemented that interacts *data access layer* : `selectedFolder` is passed as parameter to method `DeleteFolder`. The *selected node* of `TreeView` is also removed

Code has following issue: it works properly only if `DeleteFolder` called first:

1. `DeleteFolder`(`selectedFolder`) // selectedFolder is OK
2. `#.SelectedNode.Remove`

If I try :

1. `#.SelectedNode.Remove` // `AfterSelect` is called. selectedFolder is now parent node
2. `DeleteFolder`(`selectedFolder`) // selectedFolder is **wrong**

As I mentioned this code has bad smell. Is not it?

Should I make `Pull down` refactoring to make `selectedFolder` local variable. `AfterSelect` event handler **should be** *removed*.

1. Fill `selectedFolder` local var based on selected node (code from `AfterSelect` event handler)
2. `#.SelectedNode.Remove`
3. `DeleteFolder`(`selectedFolder`)

In this case is not depended on call order of `2.` and `3.`.

Comment: I'm not sure someone can understand your question and come up with an answer. Please post some code explaining what problem it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `KeyDown` event handler you already access the `TreeView` when removing the node, so yes I would definitely grab the folder name from the node before performing the other two operations, *even if the call order did not matter in the first place*.